# Finding a phone's location from its number using GPS

Tags: android, gps, location

I need to find the current longitude and latitude of a mobile phone based on its number with an Android app. I am able to get my own current location data, but I am unable to get my friend's location data. What do I have to do?

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of having your application installed on the friends mobile and having it activate a share with friends functionality (highly recommended feature for privacy reasons) there is no way of doing this.

Your application could update a server with its current location (with time-stamp) and then the friends could merely poll this data source for the current location.

But as before, steps need to be taken to ensure that the users location isn't leaked to people who shouldn't have access to it and that only authorized friends can see a persons location.

Comment: Iam  unable to understand your valuable  idea. would you please explain in-detail?

Comment: You cant just request the location of a friend based on mobile number. That data is not available. However, if you had an application on the users phone that updated a server of the users location, then your application could access that data from your server. But you'd need to create an application that maintains that location data online